# An inequality involving the probability of the maximum of partial sums

Tags: probability, inequality

I have come across the following inequality.

Let $X_{i}, 1\leq i \leq n$. Define

$S_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{j}X_{i}$;

$X^{n}_{i}=X_{i}I[|X_{i}|\leq a_{n}]$;

$S^{n}_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{j}(X_{i}^{n}-EX_{i}^{n})$,

where $I[|X_{i}|\leq a_{n}]$ is the indicator function and $a_{n}$ is some sequence.

Then

$P(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |S_{j}|\geq \epsilon a_{n}) $

$  \leq P(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |X_{j}|>a_{n}) + P(\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |S^{n}_{j}|>\epsilon a_{n}-\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |\sum_{i=1}^{j} EX_{i}^{n}|)$

How can this be proved? Also, does one need any special assumption on the dependence among the $X_{i}$, or is this result always valid?

Comment: Always valid unless I'm missing something. Try to bound $\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |S_{j}|$ by $\max_{1\leq j \leq n} |S^{n}_{j}| + \max_{1\leq j \leq n} |\sum_{i=1}^{j} EX_{i}^{n}|$ plus a remainder. When is that remainder equal to zero? Transform this to statements about probabilities by using $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c)\leq P(A\cap B) + P(B^c)$.

Comment: excellent, very clear now - thank you ever so much